# How do I create a four-dimensional array of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, gurobi

I am trying to create a four-dimensional array of pointers. The type of the array is a Gurobi type "GRBVar". However, I am unsure of the syntax to use.

```
GRBVar**** testArray = new GRBVar*** [numBuses];
        for (int i = 0; i < numBuses; i++) {
            testArray[i] = new GRBVar** [maxRoute];
            for (int j = 0; j < maxRoute; j++) {
                testArray[j] = new GRBVar* [numJobs];
                for (int k = 0; k < numJobs; k++) {
                    testArray[k] = new GRBVar[numJobs];
                }
            }
        }
```

The above causes an error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers and manual memory management in c++.

Comment: 1. @πάνταῥεῖ is right. 2. If you want to access deeper dimensionof an arrary you should use array[i][j]... etc. In your code you only access "first dimension"

Comment: @NewMe Raw c-style arrays aren't better.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But if he uses vector in the same way he uses this array it will fail anyway (accessing array in wrong way).

Comment: Looks at the warnings and errors about mismatched types in assignments that you get from the compiler -- that tells you what you need to fix.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: my eyes!! Don't write code like this in C++. Use standard containers, ie `std::vector`

Comment: Be wary of the number of each. With `100` of each, that is a minimum of `100000000 * sizeof GRBVar` bytes. With `1000` of each -- that's `1e+12 * sizeof GRBVar` bytes. (unlikely you have that much memory available). When you reach 4D, that is generally an indication you need to go back and refactor your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Literally you can create it like `GRBVar* array[10][10][10][10]`, but it's better to use nested `std::vector` for this purpose, like `std::vector<GRBVar*>`, `std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar*>>` etc, and moreover - use aliases, like

```
using Jobs = std::vector<GRBVar*>;
using Routes = std::vector<Jobs>;
using Buses = std::vector<Routes>;
```

And then initialize it:

```
Buses buses;
for (int i = 0; i < numBuses; i++) {
    Routes routes;
    for (int j = 0; j < maxRoute; j++) {
        Jobs jobs;
        for (int k = 0; k < numJobs; k++) {
            jobs.push_nack(new GRBVar);
        }
        routes.push_back(jobs);
    }
    buses.push_back(routes);
}
```

Comment: Added initialization example.

Comment: Why `std::vector<GRBVar*>` and not `std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar>>` or `std::vector<GRBVar>` ? That would avoid the `new`.

Comment: And you do a lot of unneeded copies.

Comment: Tried to introduce new features at once, that's why `GRBVar*`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses, so in the above example how would I access an element of the array for example testArray[1][2][3][4];

Comment: Yes, just like you wrote - `testArray[1][2][3][4]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `[]` levels in your nested for loops to assign the pointers to their proper objects.

```
#include <iostream>
typedef struct SomeObject { int r; } *GRBVar;  // this keeps the syntax as close as possible to the original question

int main()
{
    int numBuses = 2;
    int maxRoute = 3;
    int numJobs = 4;
    SomeObject* someobjects = new SomeObject[numBuses * maxRoute * numJobs * numJobs];

    // This creates and initializes a 4D array of pointers to SomeObjects
    GRBVar**** testArray = new GRBVar ***[numBuses];
    for (int i = 0; i < numBuses; i++) {
        testArray[i] = new GRBVar **[maxRoute];
        for (int j = 0; j < maxRoute; j++) {
            testArray[i][j] = new GRBVar *[numJobs];
            for (int k = 0; k < numJobs; k++) {
                testArray[i][j][k] = new GRBVar[numJobs];
                for (int m = 0; m < numJobs; m++)
                    testArray[i][j][k][m] = someobjects++;
            }
        }
    }
    testArray[0][0][0][0]->r = 1;
    testArray[0][0][0][1]->r = 2;
    testArray[0][0][1][0]->r = 3;

    std::cout << testArray[0][0][0][0]->r << " " << testArray[0][0][0][1]->r << " " << testArray[0][0][1][0]->r << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that while I was trying to address your specific question, this style of code is about the same efficiency as nested vectors. Much better to use `operator()` and a single, linear array, usually with a `vector<GRBVar>`

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I think I am following the example, I am fairly new to pointers and objects so will need to look into it further

Comment: Keep in mind the short example leaves a ton of dangling pointers you will have to delete. An improved (slightly) approach is using `std::unique_ptr` which automates that but I wanted to keep it as similar to your question as possible. I presume this is some sort of exercise. These levels of ptrs can be confusing but it's a good way to get an understanding of ptrs.